Priority order of running subreport in jasper report
I have 2 subreports A,B placed in the detail section of the main report, how to display the result X as the value of report A in subreport B. I have transferred the value X to the main report, but cannot transfer it to the subreport. Is there any way to set subreport A to run before subreport B?
